# i am trying to write a regex to extract endpoint in a text payload in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

hi guys i am using (*) b as a regex to extract a request method that has endpoint from a text Payload, but its fetching everything

Comment: Can you please provide more details about how your use case like which product of GCP you are using, what you are expecting to happen and is not happening, any particular document you are following to achieve your goal etc.?

Comment: @Aarti S so i managed to fetch endpoinds from api so i am able to display them under the chart but its displaying the whole textpayload so i need to filter out the rest and be left with the endpoinds so i need to write the regex that filters out everything and leave the endpoints